# Duvidas em caso de uso

Tags: uml

Gente sou novo em engenharia de software, e tenho uma duvida em casos de uso, pode o sistema ser um ator? Por exemplo em um sistema de universidade ter um caso de uso de um mecanismo de busca.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Um ator é quem fará a execução do caso de uso (quem executará a funcionalidade que está especificada no caso de uso) seja ele humano ou sistêmico e não em si uma parte do sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Consoante o  [UML - Guia do usuário](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/UML.html?id=ddWqxcDKGF8C&redir_esc=y) - BOOCH, RUMBAUCH, JACOBSON

> Ator:
>   Um ator representa um conjunto coerente de papéis que os
>   usuários de casos de uso desempenham quando interagem com esses casos
>   de uso. Tipicamente, um ator representa um papel que ***um ser humano, um
>   dispositivo de hardware ou até outro sistema desempenha com o sistema***.
>
> Por exemplo, se você trabalha em um banco, poderá ser um `AgenteDeEmpréstimo`. Se utiliza o serviço de banco pessoal, também desempenhará o papel de `cliente`. Uma instância de um ator, portanto, representa uma interação individual com o sistema de uma maneira específica. Embora você utilize atores em sua modelagem, os atores não são, de fato, parte do sistema.
>
> Eles residem fora do sistema.